# What is the name of the thing which groups applications in applications menu?

Tags: debian, gnome

When Debian desktop is installed and uses GNOME, the applications menu contains something which looks like a directory (or a grouping) called *Utilities*. Inside, there is about a dozen applications, such as the calculator and the system monitor.

How is this grouping called?

I want to be able to create my own directories, but I can't figure out how it is called, and so I don't know what to search for.

Comment: Try the maling list at "https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/" - gnome and kde similar menu systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gnome follows the [Freedesktop menu specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/menu-spec-latest.html). Its menu is assembled from several files, including `/etc/xdg/menus/gnome-applications.menu` for applications that are part of Gnome itself, `/etc/xdg/menus/applications-merged/*.menu` for third-party applications installed system-wide and `~/.config/menus/applications-merged/*.menu` for entries added by the user.

On Debian, the system files are generated by the [menu package](https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/menu.html/), which ensure that when you install an application, it'll have suitable menu entries in all installed window managers (regardless of whether they use Freedesktop menu specifications or their own format).

The content of each file is (mainly) a hierarchy of menus, submenus and menu entries. Menus from different files are [merged](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/menu-spec-latest.html#merge-algorithm), so if you define submenus with the same name in your own files, the entries will appear in the same submenu as system applications.

Entries are [`.desktop` files](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) which specify a name, an action, an icon, etc.

Based on the content of the menu files on my system, I think this should work to add `foo.desktop` to the “Applications → Utilities” menu.

```
<!DOCTYPE Menu PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD Menu 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/menu-spec/1.0/menu.dtd">
<Menu>
  <Name>Applications</Name>
  <Menu>
    <Name>Utilities</Name>
    <Include>
      <Filename>foo.desktop</Filename>
    </Include>
  </Menu>
</Menu>
```